# R - Putting time series with frequency of 20 min into the function stl()

Tags: r, stl, time-series

I am trying to use the function stl() in R to smooth a data set that stores time vs. temperature from a sensor. The main goal is to remove noise from the function, in order to find the ambient temperature (baseline curve). I have loaded my data in time series format, and when I tried to use stl(), it gave me this error:

```
Error in stl(timeseries[[1]]) : 
  series is not periodic or has less than two periods
```

here is my data:

```
> head(stations[[1]])
                 Date Unit Temp
1 0013-06-30 10:00:01    C 32.5
2 0013-06-30 10:20:01    C 32.5
3 0013-06-30 10:40:01    C 33.5
4 0013-06-30 11:00:01    C 34.5
5 0013-06-30 11:20:01    C 37.0
6 0013-06-30 11:40:01    C 35.5
```

which i have converted to time series class:

```
timeseries[[1]] = as.ts(stations[[1]]$Temp,freq=26280)
```

note : frequency is high as data is taken every 20 minutes

Is the error with stl() due to a disagreement of the frequency? I have a feeling that I may have done something wrong when making my data a time series and that this has thrown off the ability to calculate the period of the series

I do need all this data, as the entire set only covers 4 days worth of data (hence the high frequency)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: hi @user2498712.  You might want to go back through some of your old questions and accept some answers if they were resolved the issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error message tells you that in order to estimate a seasonal component of your time series, you need data for at least two seasons. If you have 4 days worth of temperature data, you probably want to have the seasonal component to be in days. Therefore you should set-up your time-series accordingly. You have 24*3 observations a day, so that should be the frequency.

```
timeseries[[1]] <- ts(stations[[1]]$Temp, frequency=24*3)
```

Then `stl(timeseries[[1]], "periodic")` should work, altough I cannot test it, since it requires data for at least 2 days, i.e. 2 hours isn't enough.

Comment: I faced this issue a few weeks ago, and I can confirm that your solution is definitely right :-)

Comment: Excellent, this worked well, thank you! One issue is that it still kept a lot of noise after smoothing. Is there another method the would be better for high frequency time series? @shadow